# Getting values from radios, how to optimize it?

Tags: javascript

is there a better way to optimize my code and to avoid duplication

```js
let results1 = document.getElementById("results1");
let results2 = document.getElementById("results2");
let results3 = document.getElementById("results3");


results1.innerHTML = '50 %';
results2.innerHTML = '100 $';
results3.innerHTML = '150 $';

document.querySelector("div.btn-group").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.type === "radio") {


    if (evt.target.value == 0) {

      console.log(evt.target.value)

      results1.innerHTML = '50 %';
      results2.innerHTML = '100 $';
      results3.innerHTML = '150 $';
    }
    if (evt.target.value == 1) {
      results1.innerHTML = '150 %';
      results2.innerHTML = '200 $';
      results3.innerHTML = '350 $';
    }
    if (evt.target.value == 2) {
      results1.innerHTML = '250 %';
      results2.innerHTML = '300 $';
      results3.innerHTML = '450 $';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
Select your plan

<div class="btn-group border" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label id='RADIO' class="btn btn-light">
            <input type="radio" name="test" value="0" checked> weekly
        </label>
  <label class="btn btn-light">
            <input type="radio" name="test" value="1"> monthly
        </label>
  <label class="btn btn-light">
            <input type="radio" name="test" value="2"> yearly
        </label>
</div>

<table class="table mt-4">
  <tr>
    <th>Weekly</th>
    <th>Montly</th>
    <th>Yearly</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="results1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="results2"></span></td>
    <td><span id="results3"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>full access</td>
    <td>free support</td>
    <td>everything</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Put the values you need to assign into a two-dimensional array? Then you can pick the right "set" based on `evt.target.value`

Comment: And if you select your target elements in a way that you can iterate over them / access them via an index (f.e. by giving the table row an id, and then using `document.querySelector('#myTableRow').querySelectorAll('span')`), then you can loop over these and your second array dimension together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the values directly inside the `option` element as `data-*` attributes and read them in the event handler

```js
let results1 = document.getElementById("results1");
let results2 = document.getElementById("results2");
let results3 = document.getElementById("results3");


results1.innerHTML = '50 %';
results2.innerHTML = '100 $';
results3.innerHTML = '150 $';

document.querySelector("div.btn-group").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.type === "radio") {
      results1.innerHTML = evt.target.dataset.r1
      results2.innerHTML = evt.target.dataset.r2
      results3.innerHTML = evt.target.dataset.r3
  }
});
```

```html
Select your plan

<div class="btn-group border" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label id='RADIO' class="btn btn-light">
            <input type="radio" name="test" value="0" checked data-r1="50 %" data-r2="100 $" data-r3="150 $"> weekly
        </label>
  <label class="btn btn-light">
            <input type="radio" name="test" value="1" data-r1="150 %" data-r2="200 $" data-r3="350 $"> monthly
        </label>
  <label class="btn btn-light">
            <input type="radio" name="test" value="2" data-r1="250 %" data-r2="300 $" data-r3="450 $"> yearly
        </label>
</div>

<table class="table mt-4">
  <tr>
    <th>Weekly</th>
    <th>Montly</th>
    <th>Yearly</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="results1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="results2"></span></td>
    <td><span id="results3"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>full access</td>
    <td>free support</td>
    <td>everything</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to optimize my code and to avoid duplication

There will be many ways to tidy up / refactor / optimize your code.

Here is just one example.

Please study it and if you have any questions ask in the comments below.

---

**Working Example of Refactored Code:**

```js
const buttons = document.querySelector('.btn-group');
let resultSpans = document.querySelectorAll('#results span');

let outputs = [
  ['50', '100', '150'],
  ['150', '200', '350'], 
  ['250', '300', '450']
];

const updateResults = (e) => {

  resultSpans.forEach((resultSpan, i) => {
  
    resultSpan.textContent = outputs[e.target.value][i] + ' ';
    resultSpan.textContent += (i === 0) ? '%' : '$';
  });
};

buttons.addEventListener('change', updateResults);
```

```html
Select your plan

<div class="btn-group border" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label id='RADIO' class="btn btn-light">
            <input type="radio" name="test" value="0" checked> weekly
        </label>
  <label class="btn btn-light">
            <input type="radio" name="test" value="1"> monthly
        </label>
  <label class="btn btn-light">
            <input type="radio" name="test" value="2"> yearly
        </label>
</div>

<table class="table mt-4">
  <tr>
    <th>Weekly</th>
    <th>Monthly</th>
    <th>Yearly</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="results">
    <td><span>50 %</span></td>
    <td><span>100 $</span></td>
    <td><span>150 $</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>full access</td>
    <td>free support</td>
    <td>everything</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to avoid repetition using high order function

```js
const results = ["results1", "results2", "results3"].map((id) =>
  document.getElementById(id)
);

const applyPrices = (prices) => (node, index) => {
  node && (node.innerHTML = prices[index]);
};

const prices = [
  ["50 %", "100 $", "150 $"],
  ["150 %", "200 $", "350 $"],
  ["250 %", "300 $", "450 $"],
];

// probably here you have to get the pices based on the pre-checked checkbox
results.forEach(applyPrices(prices[0]));

document
  .querySelector("div.btn-group")
  .addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.type === "radio") {
      const value = Number(evt.target.value);
      if (![0, 1, 2].includes(value)) {
        return;
      }

      results.forEach(applyPrices(prices[value]));
    }
  });
```

```html
Select your plan

<div class="btn-group border" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id='RADIO' class="btn btn-light">
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="0" checked> weekly
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-light">
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="1"> monthly
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-light">
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="2"> yearly
    </label>
</div>

<table class="table mt-4">
    <tr>
        <th>Weekly</th>
        <th>Montly</th>
        <th>Yearly</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span id="results1"></span></td>
        <td><span id="results2"></span></td>
        <td><span id="results3"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>full access</td>
        <td>free support</td>
        <td>everything</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```